# Product of random variables: is this approximation correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, solution-verification

Let $x$ and $y$ be two non-independent real and continuous random variables, and $p$ the following product:

$$p=\prod_{n=1}^{N}x_ne^{iy_n},$$

where the different $x_n$ are realisations of $x$, and same for $y$. I want to compute the expected value of $p$. The different realisations are independent from each other, so one safe way to me is

$$\bar p=\left (\overline{xe^{iy}} \right )^N,$$

the bar denoting the expected value. But this joint average is making me unhappy, so I am wondering if the following approximation is correct. We can write $p$ as

$$p=\left (\prod_{n=1}^{N}x_n \right ) e^{i\sum_{n=1}^N y_n}=\left (\prod_{n=1}^{N}x_n \right ) e^{iz}$$

where $z$ is a new random variable, which is Gaussian for $N$ large enough, and roughly independent of the product of the $x_n$. This would lead to

$$\bar p\approx\left (\overline{x }\right )^N \left (e^{i \bar y -  var(y)/2} \right )^N.$$

Is this correct and, if yes, is it under particular conditions on $x$ and $y$?

Note: in my particular case, I have $x\in[0, 1]$ and $y\in[0,y_{max}]$, and I'm working in a general case so I don't have constraints on their laws.

Comment: Did you mean that $x$ and $y$ are **dependent** (as you originally wrote here) or **independent**?

Comment: Dependent, otherwise the whole thing would be simple XD

Comment: For your particular case how are $x$ and $y$ dependent?

Comment: @JimB, in my case it can be any arbitrary dependence, I want to show something general so I don't make any assumptions on $x$ and $y$ (appart from their domain of definition mentioned above). But I can give you  one particular case where you would have $x \propto 1/y^4$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended comment rather than an answer.

I think you'll need to be more restrictive about the distributions (such as $E(X)$ needs to exist).
More specificity about the dependency is also needed.  Stating $X\propto 1/Y^4$ might say how $X$ and $Y$ are related in a conditional regression sense but says nothing about the joint probability density function.

You might want to consider some specific example where there is a symbolic solution to check on your approximation.  (Alternatively, performing simulations would be the next best thing.)  Here are two examples:

$X\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ and $Y\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ with $X$ and $Y$ independent:

$$E(X e^{i Y})=-\frac{1}{2} i \left(-1+e^i\right)$$

$X$ and $Y$ follow a bivariate normal distribution with mean vector $\mu=(\mu_X,\mu_Y)$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sigma^2_X  & \rho  \sigma_X  \sigma_Y  \\
 \rho  \sigma_X  \sigma^2_Y & \sigma^2_Y  \\
\end{array}
\right)$ the expectation is

$$E(X e^{i Y})=e^{-\frac{\sigma_Y^2}{2}+i \mu_Y} (\mu_X+i \sigma_X \sigma_Y \rho )$$